# Ceramic pans vs PTFE pans

Tags: frying, pan, ceramic, teflon

I want to buy ceramic pan. The shop keeper told me that ceramic pans are more durable. But they need oil.

[Here](http://www.lovelowfat.com/ceramic-vs-teflon/), I found a different info. They claimed PTFE is more durable. It says that none of them need oil and oil damages both of them. When I look for ceramic pans on shops none of them mention about none-sickness.

I do not overheat pan. So I do not care about how much they resist heat. I have several questions:

1- Are ceramic pans none-stick as much as PTFE? Do they need oil?

2- Are ceramic pans less/more durable than PTFE?

3- Are ceramic pans metal utensil safe? Do they scratch as easy as PTFE? Does stiff side of sponge damage them?

4- What happens if ceramic scratch? Should I trough it away?

5- Do ceramic keeps its none-stickness for one year?

6- To wash ceramic pan, should I use [white vinegar](http://www.lovelowfat.com/ceramic-vs-teflon/) or soda?

7- Is none-safety of PTFE about before scratching or after scratching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ceramic pans are more non-stick than PTFE. They don't need oil.
2. Ceramic pans are less durable. They fail within a few months of use.
3. Ceramic pans don't scratch, they are too hard.
4. No, don't throw it away. They don't contain the halogen elements found in PTFE.
5. I wouldn't say so. Mine and my mother's failed earlier, and I've read many reports saying the same. 6-9 months seems to be a common period for them keeping their non-stick properties.
6. Use whatever makes it clean. I prefer to use standard detergent.
7. You are cautioned against ingesting PTFE. This is only relevant after scratching. PTFE is chemically extremely durable (that's why it's nonstick) and will not enter the food unless physically damaged.

Comment: I have heard rumors of a particular brand of ceramic pan that does not fail within months, but have never met one in the wild.

Comment: Re 1: I have a ceramic pan - if I cook eggs on it without butter or oil, they stick.  They don't stick on Teflon.  Re 2: The ceramic coating is outlasting my Teflon in terms of scratches.  Re 3: Very hard to scratch, but it happens.

Answer (score 2):

I can address a few of your points.

- [Polytetrafluoroethylene (Teflon)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene) is the third most slippery substance known to man (the first two being incredibly expensive - an alloy of aluminum and Diamond-like carbon).  There is nothing used in home cooking that is more non-stick.
- Teflon pans are NOT highly vulnerable to normal use with metallic utensils.  Just don't aggressively scrape them.
- Teflon's safety is related to off gassing under high heat.
- Ceramic is a loaded term.  There are many, many coatings that are ceramic, and they all have different properties, where as PTFE is exactly one type of coating.  Judgements of 'ceramic' are not really reliable.  A specific pan or coating technique are the only tangible thing that can be judged.